# Separating dates between a date range in Google Data Studio

Tags: date, looker-studio, date-range

I have two dimensions in Google Data Studio in the format Date (From,To) from an external source and now I want to display all days within the time space individually.

Ex: 01.10.2020 - 05.10.2020

| ---result as table--- |
| --- |
| 01.10.2020 |
| 02.10.2020 |
| 03.10.2020 |
| 04.10.2020 |
| 05.10.2020 |

That's it. I just can't find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

I understand that your ultimate goal is to join the two dates into a single field in the format 01.10.2020 - 05.10.2020.

To do this, you can create a new field that contains the formula:

```
CONCAT(Date1, ' - ',Date2)
```

And after, insert this new field in your table. The output format of this formula will be a text type element.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, however the ultimate goal is actually to get individual days to then evaluate how many days are occupied in which month etc.